# After connecting to private VPN server my Internet disconnects

Tags: networking, vpn

Right after connecting to a private VPN my internet disconnects. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Can anyone help me with this? What information should I provide to help investigating the problem?

More information:

**Internet Connection before connecting to VPN**

Output of command `ip -r`

```
default via 192.199.0.2 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
188.18.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 188.18.0.1 
192.199.0.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.199.0.18 metric 100 
192.199.123.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.199.123.1 linkdown
```

Output of command `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.199.0.2     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
188.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.199.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
192.199.123.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

**After connecting the VPN**

Output of command `ip -r`

```
default via 175.19.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.199.0.2 dev enp7s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.1.1.0/24 via 175.19.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
10.100.0.0/16 via 175.19.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
10.130.0.0/17 via 175.19.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
175.19.2.0/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 175.19.2.15 metric 50 
188.18.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 188.18.0.1 
192.199.0.0/24 dev enp7s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.199.0.18 metric 100 
192.199.0.2 dev enp7s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.199.123.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.199.123.1 linkdown 
192.199.200.0/24 via 175.19.2.1 dev tun1 proto static metric 50 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx via 192.199.0.2 dev enp7s0 proto static metric 100
```

Output of command `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         175.19.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         192.199.0.2     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp7s0
10.1.1.0        175.19.2.1      255.255.255.0   UG    50     0        0 tun1
10.100.0.0      175.19.2.1      255.255.0.0     UG    50     0        0 tun1
10.130.0.0      175.19.2.1      255.255.128.0   UG    50     0        0 tun1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
175.19.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun1
188.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.199.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0
192.199.0.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp7s0
192.199.123.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.199.200.0   175.19.2.1      255.255.255.0   UG    50     0        0 tun1
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 192.199.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp7s0
```

Here are the VPN configuration in the following images.  Unfortunatelly, I can not show all the information

[image: VPN configuration]

[image: VPN advanced configuration - General]

[image: VPN advanced configuration - Security]

[image: VPN advanced configuration - TLS Authentication]

After that the internet of the first connection does not work anymore.

I am suspicious about the routing but I am not sure.  Please help me out on this.

Comment: Hello. I see this is your first post, wellcome to superuser. Please, when you post a question try to be much more specific. There are, literally, thousands of possible scenarios that cover your question. What is your OS? Network configuration? Software used for VPN? Server and client side configurations? Error logs?

Comment: I have added more information.  Please let me know if you need more to help me on this

Comment: Hello. I see some things that I usually do in a different way, I'll read a bit to determine if that setup is correct, however, I need to know what do you want to achieve. Do you want to a) Pass ALL your outgoing traffic through the VPN or B) Connect to some specific networks (a job network, for instance) via the VPN but access everywhere else through your normal connection? The answer is different depending the case.

Comment: By the way, the last line in the Output of command route -n and Output of command route -n is showing the public IP of your VPN, I think. I suggest you to replace the last row's "Destination" field with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in both outputs if my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for editing your post to clarify.

If I get it right, what you want to do is connect to some specific networks (172.16.2.0, 192.168.200.0 and the 10.x.x.x ones) via the VPN, while connecting to Internet and everywhere else using your normal connection.

Instead of that, you observe the following behaviour:

- You can connect to computers in the remote network
- You CAN NOT access the Internet, or if you do it happend through the VPN, making it much slower or giving you other kind of problems

If that is the case, run the proper commands in order to remove this line:

```
0.0.0.0         172.16.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun1
```

which is telling your system that ALL the traffic should be router through the VPN. This is called "default gateway", however who knows how the VPN GUI calls to this.

The proper command to do so manually is:

```
sudo ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 172.16.2.1 dev tun1
```

This is a workaround, though, as your VPN client will keep updating your route everytime it reconnects (or even more frecuently, depending on the vpn version and internal settings). I never configure VPNs with GUI, I'm a command line guy who allways uses config files, but there's a setting to avoid this (maybe it is in Misc section?). You need to google about how to prevent your specific vpn to set the vpn server as the ***default gateway*** (that's the key concept of all this)

Answer (score 0):

What I want is to connect to some specific services via VPN but access anything else through my normal connection.

Turns out that the GUI networking setup was not working at all, so after connecting the VPN through this command solved my problem:

```
sudo openvpn --config vpn-config-file.ovpn
```